# Using regex to strip numbers inside curly braces at the start of the string in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a column of a pandas dataframe (`df`). It looks like this:

```
Mese
__________
{12313}Luglio
{34}Maggio
```

I was trying to use regex to get rid of the `{}` and everything in between:

```
df['Mese']=[re.sub(r'^{d+}','', str(x)) for x in df['Mese']]
```

It does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Series.str.replace` with `^\{\d+}` pattern:

```
 df['Mese'] = df['Mese'].str.replace(r'^\{\d+}', '')
```

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Mese':['{12313}Luglio','{34}Maggio']})
>>> df['Mese'] = df['Mese'].str.replace(r'^\{\d+}', '')
>>> df
     Mese
0  Luglio
1  Maggio
```

The `^\{\d+}` [pattern matches](https://regex101.com/r/HwgHd0/1) a number inside curly braces at the start of the string.